# How to install latest ffmpeg on mac

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, terminal, osx-lion

I am using this command

```
sudo port install ffmpeg +gpl +postproc +lame +theora +libogg +vorbis +xvid +x264 +a52 +faac +faad +dts +nonfree
```

But the installed version of ffmpeg I get is only 0.7.13.

I am using MacPorts which may be the issue

Apparently there is a 1.0 release!
http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#release_1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "problem" with MacPorts. As you say, the last port version is 0.7.13. There is also a [devel port](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/multimedia/ffmpeg-devel/Portfile) but with a recent revision (5 weeks ago). You could also take a look [here](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/). This site seems to have a 1.0 static binary. It is a trusted website. Actually is linked in the official ffmpeg website.

Comment: Thanks. Yes grabbed the static binary. But needed Unarchiver to extract.

Answer (score 16):

**1. Homebrew**

Homebrew has a formula for stable FFmpeg releases. This will get you running pretty fast. First, install Homebrew by opening Terminal.app and and pasting this. Follow all the instructions closely!

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install FFmpeg through the ffmpeg formula:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

This will download a lot of dependencies such as x264, LAME, FAAC, et cetera, but after that you should be good to go. You can also `brew install ffmpeg --HEAD` to get the absolute latest version.

For additional options, check the output of brew info ffmpeg. You can, for example, add the following options, which are normally disabled:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265
```

To update ffmpeg later on, run:

```
brew update && brew upgrade ffmpeg
```

**2. Static Builds**

The FFmpeg project, on the download page, offers links to static builds for ffmpeg, which you can just download, extract, and use in a terminal.

At the moment, you can get them from here:

- http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/
- http://ffmpegmac.net/

Static builds cannot contain every possible encoder, mostly due to licensing issues. This is why I don't recommend using them unless you don't really care about which specific features you need.

Once downloaded, extract the file, open up Terminal.app, and navigate to the directory where you unzipped the files, i.e. where you find a file called ffmpeg. Copy this file to /usr/local/bin:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp ./ffmpeg /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Now, if you use Bash (which is the default shell), add it to your $PATH:

```
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this to the file at the end:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Save it, and close the editor. Now restart your Terminal and which ffmpeg should return `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: after runing above scripts, when i run : "ffmpeg -version" , getting ERROR : `-bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied`

Comment: have you tried with sudo? and checked the executable permission for the user?